# What is the relationship between radius and tangential velocity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, everyday-life, angular-velocity

So imagine you had a tennis racket. Let's say it is 27 inches. The swinger will swing the racket and at the tip of the racket it's going a certain speed.

If we increased the length of the racket to 29 inches, is the increase of speed at the tip linear or is it exponential?

Thanks for the help guys, this wasn't a homework question btw, i was just curious.

Comment: Are you more interested in the speed of the racket or of the ball?  First google result that might be helpful was [this](https://twu.tennis-warehouse.com/learning_center/racquetcontribution.php).

Comment: i assumed the speed at the tip of the racket = the ball right? But someone already answered it as linear thanks

Comment: If you can keep the angular velocity same somehow then the velocity increases linearly with radius. (v = rw)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that it's harder to swing a bigger racket as fast, yes the relationship is linear. Since the racket is rigid, its *angular* velocity has to be constant as it pivots, and you can find the relationship between velocity and angular velocity as

$$v = \omega r$$

where $\omega$ is the angular velocity.